# Getting details of a song in Music Library from iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have read and done my research on the implementation of selecting a song from the music library with MPMediaPickerController. My question is once my user has selected the song they want, is it possible to get information on that song such as its length and to play it from a certain point for a certain duration instead of playing the entire song.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Info on: [MPMediaPickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)
which links to [MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate_ProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate)
which then links to [MPMediaItemCollection](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItemCollection_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMediaItemCollection) and finally the [MPMediaItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMediaItem) where you can obtain various properties for the song.  Check out the section labeled: **General Media Item Property Keys**. You can obtain the length using the MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration key.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to play the MPMediaItem from a certain point? And what is used to play it? Thanks

Comment: Try the MPMusicPlayerController.  I believe there are methods to achieve that such as the currentPlaybackTime property: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Ok cools thanks so the MPMusicPlayer accepts type of MPMediaItem?